# How to render datatable with radiobutton inputs per each row in R Shiny multiple times without generating new inputs each time

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a R Shiny app with datatable in which there is an input field at each row. I was able to implement it whenever the data is static - generated one time. But in my app the user need to load the data multiple times and each time to fill in the input and submit, and then load another dataset.

In the first load the input works well, but on the change of data it is probably try to re-render the input fields, and they stop responding. I hacked it with creating a new input ids per data load, but this solution may end with thousands of inputs if the user have many dataset to go over.

I short, I would like to implement this without the values$j index: (paste0("answers_",values$j,"_", i)).

thanks,

p.s. with renderTable it works, but I need the render
I have a minimum reproducible example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)


ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput("selected_project", "Select project",choices=c("A","B"),multiple=FALSE,selected = "A")
    ,selectInput("maximum_questions_to_show", "Maximum questions to show",choices=c(5,10),multiple=FALSE,selected = 10)
    ,actionButton("submit_answers","Submit")
    ,verbatimTextOutput('answersText')
    ,DT::dataTableOutput("answerTable")
    # ,tableOutput("answerTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    values <- reactiveValues(j=0)

    getData<-eventReactive(c(input$selected_project,input$maximum_questions_to_show), {
        values$j=values$j+1
        print("BBB")
        if(input$selected_project=="A")
            data<-data.frame("project"=rep("A",30),"id"=paste0("A_",1:30),"answers"=rep("n",30),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        if(input$selected_project=="B")
            data<-data.frame("project"=rep("B",50),"id"=paste0("B_",1:50),"answers"=rep("n",50),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        nrows<-min(dim(data)[1],as.numeric(input$maximum_questions_to_show))
        data=data[1:nrows,]
        answers<-sapply(1:nrows,function(i) {
                as.character(radioButtons(inputId=paste0("answers_",values$j,"_", i), label=paste0("answers_",values$j,"_", i)
                , choices=c("n","y"),selected=data$answers[i],inline=TRUE))
        })
        # answers<-sapply(1:nrows,function(i) {
        #         as.character(radioButtons(inputId=paste0("answers_", i), label=paste0("answers_", i)
        #         , choices=c("n","y"),selected=data$answers[i],inline=TRUE))
        # })
        data$answers<-answers
        return(list("data"=data))
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


    output$answerTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        data<-getData()$data

        data.table(
                "project"=data[,"project"]
                ,"id"=data[,"id"]
                ,"answers" = data[,"answers"]
        )

        },editable = TRUE,escape=FALSE,selection = 'none', server = FALSE,rownames = FALSE,
                        ,options = list(dom="Bftsp",lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),pageLength = 5,paging=TRUE
                                                 ,preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }')
                                                 ,drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
    )

        # output$answerTable <- renderTable({
        #     data<-getData()$data
        #     data[,c("id","answers")]
        # },sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

    answers_results <- reactive({
        data<-getData()$data
        nrows<-dim(data)[1]
        (sapply(1:nrows, function(i) input[[paste0("answers_",values$j,"_", i)]]))
        # (sapply(1:nrows, function(i) input[[paste0("answers_", i)]]))
    })

    output$answersText = renderPrint({
        unlist(lapply(answers_results() , function(x) ifelse(is.null(x),"n",x)))
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit_answers,{
        print(unlist(lapply(answers_results() , function(x) ifelse(is.null(x),"n",x))))
    })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to unbind each time there's a rendering. Here I run the unbinding in `getData`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
  )),
  selectInput(
    "selected_project", 
    "Select project", 
    choices = c("A", "B"), 
    multiple = FALSE, 
    selected = "A"
  ),
  selectInput(
    "maximum_questions_to_show", 
    "Maximum questions to show", 
    choices = c(5, 10), 
    multiple = FALSE, 
    selected = 10
  ),
  actionButton("submit_answers", "Submit"),
  verbatimTextOutput("answersText"),
  DTOutput("answerTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  getData <- eventReactive(
    c(input$selected_project, input$maximum_questions_to_show),
    {
      session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "answerTable")
      print("BBB")
      if(input$selected_project == "A"){
        data <- data.frame(
          "project" = rep("A", 30), 
          "id" = paste0("A_", 1:30), 
          "answers" = rep("n", 30), 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      }else{
        data <- data.frame(
          "project" = rep("B", 50), 
          "id" = paste0("B_", 1:50), 
          "answers" = rep("n", 50), 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      }
      nrows <- min(nrow(data), as.numeric(input$maximum_questions_to_show))
      data <- data[1:nrows, ]
      answers <- sapply(1:nrows, function(i){
        as.character(
          radioButtons(inputId=paste0("answers_", i), 
                       label=paste0("answers_", i),
                       choices=c("n","y"),
                       selected=data$answers[i],
                       inline=TRUE)
        )
      })
      data$answers <- answers
      return(list("data" = data))
    },
    ignoreNULL = FALSE
  )

  output$answerTable <- renderDT(
    {
      data <- getData()$data[, c("project", "id", "answers")]
      datatable(
        data,
        editable = TRUE,
        escape = FALSE,
        selection = "none",
        rownames = FALSE,
        options = list(
          dom = "Bftsp", 
          lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c("5", "15", "All")), 
          pageLength = 5, 
          paging = TRUE,
          preDrawCallback = 
            JS("function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
          drawCallback = 
            JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ")
        )
      )
    },
    server = FALSE
  )

  answers_results <- reactive({
    data <- getData()$data
    nrows <- nrow(data)
    (sapply(1:nrows, function(i) input[[paste0("answers_", i)]]))
  })

  output$answersText <- renderPrint({
    unlist(lapply(answers_results(), function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), "n", x)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit_answers, {
    print(unlist(lapply(answers_results(), function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), "n", x))))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```